# Application of distance between probability measures

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value

Let $P\sim Q$ be two *equivalent* probability measures. There seem to exsist different notions of how to define a difference between the two probability measures/distributions. For example,

- **Total variation:** $$\delta(P,Q)=\sup_{A} |P(A)-Q(A)|$$
- **Kullback–Leibler divergence:** $$D_{KL}(P,Q)=\int_\mathbb{R}p(x)\ln\left(\frac{p(x)}{q(x)}\right)\mathrm{d}x$$
- **Hellinger distance**: $$H^2(P,Q)=\int_\mathbb{R}\left(\sqrt{p(x)}-\sqrt{q(x)}\right)^2\mathrm{d}x$$
- **Bhattacharyya distance:** $$B(P,Q)=-\ln\left(\int_\mathbb{R}\sqrt{p(x)q(x)}\mathrm{d}x\right)$$
- **Jensen–Shannon divergence:** $$JSD(P,Q)=\frac{1}{2}D_{KL}\left(P,\frac{P+Q}{2}\right)+\frac{1}{2}D_{KL}\left(Q,\frac{P+Q}{2}\right)$$

I've got two questions.

1. What is the intuitive meaning? Is it as simple as: if the distance between $P$ and $Q$ is big, then an unlikely event under $P$ may be very likely under $Q$ and vice versa?
2. Does any of these differences tell me anything about how $E^P[X]$ differs from $E^Q[X]$ for a measurable random variable $X$? What about higher moments of $X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is not complete, just a piece of useful intuition.

I can speak for the KL-Divergence with some intuitions of a related quantity.

Firstly note that KL Divergence is not a metric, $D_{KL}(P,Q) \neq D_{KL}(Q,P)$. Hence this measure of "distance" doesn't agree to our intuition of the metric.

To see then what it is worth for, let us suppose that $(X,Y)\sim P_{XY}$. Then if we choose, $P=P_{XY}$ and $Q=P_{X}P_{Y}$ then, $$D_{KL}(P,Q)=\mathbb{E}\left[\log\frac{P_{XY}}{P_Xp_Y}\right]$$ When is $D_{KL}(P,Q)=0$?

This happens exactly when $P_{XY}=P_XP_Y$. In other words, $X,Y$ are independent random variables. Hence for this case, $D_{KL}$ measures "how much" the random variables are independent of each other.

(*If you are familiar with Information Theory, $D_{KL}(P_{XY},P_XP_Y)=I(X;Y)$ is know as the Mutual Information between $X,Y$.*)

The Jensen–Shannon divergence is an extension of KL Divergence to make it symmetric about its arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input. Great to know that these distances are no metrics! Do you know whether a proper metric exists which is well-defined for measures? And do you have some insights on the difference between $E^P[X]$ and $E^Q[X]$?